# Duplicate script tag in blade.php file

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade

I'm using PhpStorm 2019.3.1 and I see this error. How to fix this problem?

[image: Duplicate tag error]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Do you have these script tags in different blade files?

Comment: I describe it as the post title, it's okay that it has been processed!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a bug in IDE (in one of the bundled plugins to be precise). To get rid of it you would have to disable Vue.js plugin (worked well for me, especially since I do not use Vue)...

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42930 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

As per [@lena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena) comment: as a workaround, you can disable **Vue | Duplicate template/script tag** inspection in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections`

---

**P.S.** This issue can be reproduced with any project with `vue` npm package installed.

If you do not use Vue in your projects, I guess getting rid of `package.json` or at very least `vue` entry from there should also do the trick.

---

**UPDATE 2020-03-05:**
The aforementioned ticket is now marked as fixed for 2020.1 version.

Comment: As a workaround, you can disable **Vue | Duplicate template/script tag** inspection in **Settings | Editor | Inspections**